# Debugging IE11 "Page cannot be displayed" scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, internet-explorer-11

IE produces a 'Page can't displayed' error when I am trying to submit a HTML form with specific data. I know for sure it is not an infrastructure (connection, DNS etc) problem because this works with exactly the same form having different data.

The form is submitted with `form.submit`. I am not able to catch any exception in my Javascript. The submit goes OK and then at some point IE produces the error message.

Is there any way to debug 'Page can't be displayed' in IE11 debugger to catch exactly what is happening? Thank you all.

Comment: It sounds like the server is generating an error when you submit your form. What is the difference between the form data that works, and the form data that gives this error? There is your problem.

Comment: Nothing there. My application logs have no trace of this exception.

Comment: First place to check, the Network tab of F12 tool. Also, does it happen in all browsers ?

Comment: I did not try it yet.

Comment: I'm not familiar with IE any more but I believe 11 has a quite decent console. If it's a server-side 500 Internal Server Error you should see it there.

Comment: I already tried Network tab and Console tab. No trace. it goes from nothing to the final error message.

Comment: I tried this on Chrome and get the This site cannot be reached. Again nothin in Console or Network tabs.

Comment: Good, there's your answer - your Submit isn't reaching the site. All you have to do now is work out why. Start with Rory McCrossan's question about the difference between the two bits of form data.

Comment: OK, can a 500 error on server produce Page can't be displayed in the browser? I found IOException in the server logs, but when I try to throw it artificially in my dev env it produces 500. But I have Tomcat in dev and Weblogic in prod where the original prolem happens.

Comment: I have the impression that the server is crashing before it has the chance of sending a response with status code 500.

Comment: I found out that when POST body contains closing bracket ) the header content-length is smaller than the actual request body length. Without the closing bracket these 2 numbers are identical.
Any ideas why IE does that and what I can do about this?
Thank you.